# PHP - Browser BACK button crashes the website

Tags: php, back-button

I am a newbie to programming. I have a PHP website which works as follows

Index Page    -    Search Results      -    Show a Product

The site user enters search critera on Index Page and the page is POSTed to Search Results page. From there, the site user clicks on a Product  href that takes him to the Product Details. This is working fine till here.

The problem occurs when the user click the browser BACK button. The Search Result page comes up totally crashed and the user has to press F5/Browser Refresh to re-submit it. Any idea/technqiue that I can use to avoid this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browser goes back to a page that comes from POSTing some data, the browser often times needs to re-POST the data in order to get the same page back.  Since that can sometimes be bad (e.g. re-POSTing an order form), many browsers require the user to force a refresh with a warning.

You can generally use a GET instead of a POST form to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be using GET for the method of your search form instead of POST (that apparently you are using). That way, even if going back in browser history, your server could re-supply its search results.

You would need the following:

- change `method="post"` to `method="get"` in your search form
- change every `$_POST` relating to the search form data to `$_GET` in your search form processing php file.

Of course, it could not work for your specific usecase. That's just an idea.